# Why do we need a SynchronizationContext in the EventAggregator for WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, eventaggregator, synchronizationcontext

I have read quiet a few implementations of the EventAggregator (Messenger) to communicate between different ViewModels in WPF but I am having difficulties why we necessarily need to use a `SynchronizationContext`.

I understand that the `SynchronizationContext` is used to ensure that a Post/Send action runs on the same context's thread. What advantage does it provide in the case of an EventAggregator. Rather, could someone provide and example where the EA would fail if a `SynchronizationContext` was not used.

Comment: I bet the default used is the DispatcherSynchronizationContext and the Dispatcher in question is the UI's dispatcher.  That would allow the EA a UI-agnostic way to communicate with the UI without having to worry about marshalling the call onto the UI thread on the receiving end.  You can verify this by examining the SC at runtime.

Comment: Why there's the [tag:prism] tag? Are you asking about the PRISM's `EventAggregator`?

Comment: Yes the EventAggregator in PRISM.